# App Store on High Sierra suggests Mojave-only updates

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update, iwork, mojave

I'm currently on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) and I've just received three update notifications from the Mac App Store:

1. Keynote 8.2 update
2. Numbers 5.2 update, and
3. Pages 7.2 update

All of them are marked with **Requires macOS Mojave and iOS 12** note - and when I try to *Update* any of them or all at once, nothing happens (I've tried to reboot the OS already). I want to stick to macOS High Sierra for now, and as far as I know, macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 will be supported for quite a long period of time, same as all previous macOS versions in the past.

Do these macOS Mojave only updates suggest that any further iWork office suite updates will support only the latest, upcoming macOS Mojave? How about security and other bug fixes then? What if one wants to stick to macOS High Sierra until its end-of-life but keep all their apps (including iWork) up-to-date (at least when it comes to bug fixes, not necessarily new features)?

Is is possible to mark these updates as ignored, but still receive any bug-fixing updates e.g. for Numbers 5.1? Does Apple even support its office suite for anything but their newest OS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current latest version of the three iWork apps (as mentioned in the question), are supported on macOS High Sierra 10.13 and iOS 11. You are right, that the apps as well as the OS will be well supported into the future.

### 1. Pages

[image] [image]

### 2. Keynote

[image] [image]

### 3. Numbers

[image] [image]

However, as mentioned in the release notes for the apps, certain features require the app to be running on macOS Mojave and Siri shortcuts requires iOS 12 which is the first iOS version to support this feature.

1. Pages for macOS
   [What's new in Version 7.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pages/id409201541)

> Support for Continuity Camera allows you to take a photo or scan a document with your iPhone and have it automatically appear in your document on your Mac. Requires macOS Mojave and iOS 12.

Pages for iOS
[What's new in Version 4.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/pages/id361309726)

> Support for Siri Shortcuts. Requires iOS 12.

2. Keynote for macOS
   [What's new in Version 8.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/keynote/id409183694)

> Support for Continuity Camera allows you to take a photo or scan a document with your iPhone and have it automatically appear in your presentation on your Mac. Requires macOS Mojave and iOS 12.

Keynote for iOS
[What's new in Version 4.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/keynote/id361285480)

> Support for Siri Shortcuts. Requires iOS 12.

3. Numbers for macOS
   [What's new in Version 5.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/numbers/id409203825)

> Support for Continuity Camera allows you to take a photo or scan a document with your iPhone and have it automatically appear in your spreadsheet on your Mac. Requires macOS Mojave and iOS 12.

Numbers for iOS
[What's new in Version 4.2](https://itunes.apple.com/app/numbers/id361304891)

> Support for Siri Shortcuts. Requires iOS 12.

Comment: You're right. Keynote 8.2 update and other iWork apps still support macOS High Sierra (and presumably previous macOS versions as well). It's only Continuity Camera feature included in that update, that requires Mojave or iOS 12. I thought that macOS High Sierra might not be supported by this update as the _Update_ button acted as no-op, even after my first reboot. Maybe that was some App Store issue.